# How to let `sort | uniq -c` separate the number of occurrences by a tab character?

Tags: awk, cut, uniq

`uniq -c` separates the occurrence number by spaces, which is hard for `cut` or `awk` to separate it out later.

```
1000_A1\tB1\n
___1_A2\tB2\n
```

I can solve this problem using `sed -r 's/^ *([0-9]+)/\1\t/'` to change the delimiter to tab. Then `cut -f1` could return:

```
1000\tA1\tB1\n
1\tA2\tB2\n
```

But it seems a common usage to have `uniq -c` separate the number by tab. Why is this feature missing? Is there any other easier way to do so?

Comment: Doesn't "-c" just check whether the input is sorted?  Where are you getting the output "1000 Field A", etc... from?

Comment: Are you talking about `sort | uniq -c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've got a format like `<number><space><field 1 name><tab><field 2 name>`, and you want to check that the input is sorted by `field 1 name`. If that's what you want, simply remove the initial number part and check the sorting of the remaining part of the first column:

```
echo "$input" | sed -r 's/^ *[^ ]+ //' | sort -c -k1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think it's hard for `awk` to separate the number. `awk '{print $1}'` prints it without a problem.

```
$ sort file | uniq -c
      5 x
     10 y
$ sort file | uniq -c | awk '{print $1}'
5
10
$
```

Comment: If the rows contain space, this won't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use cut to separate them out. Just use `cut -d " " -f 1` to get the number and `cut -d " " -f 2-` to get the rest. Awk will just process it as it is whitespace.

Comment: `cut -d " " -f 1` doesn't always cut the number out. Note that it's "___1_A2\tB2\n".

Answer (score 0):

may be this will easily work !!!

```
sort input_file | uniq -c | awk {'print $1 "\t" $2'} > tab_output
```

Comment: I don't know why they downvote you. This works fine, like `sed -r 's/^ *([^ ]+) +/\1\t/'`, [`sed -e 's/ *//' -e 's/ /\t/'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11670891/4970442) and [`sed -E 's/^ *//; s/ /\t/'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38337301/4970442).

Answer (score 0):

If data columns can contain spaces you can use `sed` to replace space with a tab.

```
sed -e 's/<5 white space chars>//' | sed -e 's/<1 white space chars>/\t/'
```

First `sed` replaces leading white spaces generated by `-c` switch and the second one replaces white space between count and first data column.